# How to run ntp command every x seconds?

Tags: linux, ntp

I need to open ***ntpq*** in order to query ntp services and then run the ***peers*** command to see the results:

[image]

However the problem I am having is that i need to run this ***peers*** command every x seconds. I have tried using the watch command but this does not work within ntpq. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `watch -n 1 ntpq -c peers`

Comment: Perfect  thanks for the help